# Measured signal from tachometer has ripples, why and how to minimize?

Tags: signal-analysis, continuous-signals

I don't know if it would be straightforward enough to chalk it up to this being a real system. Thus there's friction and physical mechanics of gears and teeth pulling.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Well, regarding the why: don't know the underlying mechanism of your tachometer; there's many, many ways to build one.

Minimization: compared to your signal of interest, these seem to be rather high in frequency. So, a reasonably designed low-pass filter will help. Don't forget to account for group delay, should you need to feed back the resulting signal in e.g. a control system.